# How to search and return a specific value in a row (Google sheets/Excel)

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Working on a scheduling file.
What would be the easiest way to find what was the last day someone worked in  this sheet.

"C" means someone has worked that day and dates are in row 2,

Basically searching for last value "C" in row 16 and returning date from row 2.

I am very new google sheets

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Google Sheets is *not* Excel. Make sure the tags you're using are accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel

```
=XLOOKUP("C",16:16,2:2,,0,-1)
```

Search for "C" in row 16, exact match, last to first, return from row 2

<sub>Requires Excel365</sub>